# Send input javascript, on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Does someone have any idea why only the second time I run my code it does work?

```
ThisElement = document.querySelector("#side > div._1Ra05 > div > label > div > div._1awRl.copyable-text.selectable-text");

ThisElement.innerText = 'message';

var focusEvent = new FocusEvent('focus', {
  bubbles: false,
  cancelBubble: false,
  cancelable: false,
  composed: true,
  currentTarget: null,
  defaultPrevented: false,
  detail: 0,
  eventPhase: 0,
  isTrusted: true,
});

ThisElement.dispatchEvent(focusEvent);
```

https://youtu.be/yrD9jB1FXHo

The code just sends a message in the search box.

I'm testing it on chrome using the DevTools console (F12).

Comment: I think you are the first person, who presented code as youtube video. ;-) It is better when you create a minimal runnable example by wrapping your code into the iternal script editor.

Comment: I tried the same code with a different query Selector. It worked in the first attempt

Comment: @Master.Deep in what page and what browser? I'm tying on web whatsapp, I have uploaded a better video, if you could check

Comment: I tried it on some random page and in chrome toolbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the React JS used to design whatsapp web, so to manage this you can call again event in the setTimeout

Reason behind this issue:
On the first event trigger the whatsapp web screen will release all the input focused from the app screen, so it is required to again trigger event to stimulate human action in browser.

```
        function searchContact(contact_name = "") {
        search = document.querySelector('#side > div._1Ra05 > div > label > div > div._1awRl.copyable-text.selectable-text');

        var focusEvent = new FocusEvent('focus', {
            bubbles: true,
            cancelBubble: false,
            cancelable: true,
            composed: true,
            currentTarget: null,
            defaultPrevented: false,
            detail: 0,
            eventPhase: 0,
            isTrusted: true,
        });

        //Enter value in search box events
        var inputEvent = new InputEvent('input', {
            bubbles: true
        });

        search.textContent = contact_name;
        search.dispatchEvent(focusEvent);
        search.dispatchEvent(inputEvent);


        setTimeout(function() {

            search.textContent = contact_name;
            search.dispatchEvent(focusEvent);
            search.dispatchEvent(inputEvent);
        
            el = document.querySelector("#side > div._1Ra05 > div > label > div > div._1awRl.copyable-text.selectable-text");
            var event = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
                code: 'Enter',
                key: 'Enter',
                keyCode: 13,
                view: window,
                bubbles: true
            });

            el.dispatchEvent(event);
            
        }, 1000)

    }

    searchContact("name");
    
    function triggerMouseEvent(el, etype) {
        console.log(el)
        var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        evt.initMouseEvent(etype, true, true, window,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
        el.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
```